# How can i embed a video player in moodle.?

Tags: php, video, embed, video-streaming, moodle

1. I have some video files that will be played with the help of a video player.
2. I want to embed a video player in my script which will play these video files in moodle 1.9.
3. I cannot upload those video files on some video hosting sites because those are copy protected.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dinesh,

You have not mentioned what type of video files you are using, or the type of media player which you prefer.   If it is a common format mpeg, flv, avi, m4v, quicktime, or realplayer then the media filters built in to moodle might help you.  Moodle can detect links to media files, and replace them with an embedded player.

http://docs.moodle.org/en/Multimedia_plugins

Here's how to do it:

Turn on Modules / Filters / Multimedia filter
Then configure using Modules / Filters / Multimedia Plugins

Uploading the video file to a moodle course or to the front page files area.  You may have to do this directly to your moodledata directory on your server if the file is too large to upload using a web based upload.

Then add a normal link eg <a href="my-video.flv">myvideo</a>.  You can do this almost anywhere that moodle allows you to enter rich text.

So you could add it to a course page by adding a link into the a topic description in a course, or by creating a separate moodle "web page resource", which includes a similar link.

With media filters turned on, moodle will try to replace the link to the media file with a suitable embedded media player.

This works well for short video clips and audio, but long video files might require a more complex solution and performance will depend on how you are hosting your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **moodle-mplayer** Activity ( http://code.google.com/p/moodle-mplayer/ ).

After you installed it on your server you will be able to add a new Activity which will enable you to add videos into your courses + set special video related settings for each one.

btw, there is a Kaltura plugin for Moodle that might interest you too.
http://www.kaltura.org/kaltura-moodle-plugin-installation-guide

Comment: The problem is that mplayer is not working with moodle 2+, so I'm looking for another solution.